# Can’t update existing view with each-in helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

We are creating a Sportsbook web app using Emberjs, where we retrieve data through an API and draw the view.

The received data is an object with many nested levels. Based on this object we have constructed the template file(.hbs) using each-in helper!

We are unable to use 'each' helper as we are receiving object, not array!

After the first retrieval, we are receiving updates every milliseconds and need to update the view as well by changing only the difference.

Sometimes we are receiving new entries in the object, and as the object itself is big, we need to add the new entry to the layout without redrawing the whole stuff.

Here is the problem: Each-in is not observable in this case, so it is not redrawing after pushing the new object.

Question: Is there a good way to implement this with Ember or is there a known helper that we can use instead of each-in, OR is there someone who can recommend me if we CAN create a new helper for this?

Comment: Just make ur own component. A helper won't really help with the redraw part

Comment: The api you're using does not sound like it's using some kind of standard, or that it's under your control ? Are you using ember-data with it ? If not, have you considered transforming that result from the api to something more usable ?

Comment: Just call `rerender` on your component. [Thanks to glimmer it will perform nicely.](https://ember-twiddle.com/0ba9b9c4ff76fe50a9e552fe0974dda4?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)